# incompatible types: Fragment cannot be converted to Activity

Tags: android

Any help is welcome
Using tabbed activity from android studio example whit legacy android studio libreries
My code:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.epicmario71.globalfortress.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link Fragment1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Fragment1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }

    String url = "wwww.epicmario71.tk";

    public void OpenRadio(View view) {
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
    }
}
```

full error: error: incompatible types: Fragment1 cannot be converted to Activity
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
^

any help is welcome             any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Instead of this, you have to pass the activity context.
you can use :-

```
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse(url));
```

or

```
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(url));
```

to solve the problem hopefully.